# Use of infinite loop in AtomicInteger.addAndGet(int)

Tags: java, for-loop, integer, infinite-loop, atomic

In Java's package java.util.concurrent.atomic AtomicInteger class has a method [addAndGet(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#AtomicInteger.addAndGet%28int%29)

which is

```
public final int addAndGet(int delta) {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + delta;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return next;
    }
}
```

Why it uses infinite loop here to set a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classical example of [CAS loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap). The compare-and-set is an atomic operation which has direct hardware support (usually there's some CPU instruction behind it). It atomically updates the given variable only if current value is equal to the expected one and returns true if everything was successful. Normally this loop is executed only once. However under contention (when other threads try to update the same value) it's possible that between reading current value via `get()` and updating it via `compareAndSet` another thread managed to update it. In this case the whole procedure is retried until success.

Using infinite loop here is just a matter of style. It could be rewritten using normal `do-while` loop:

```
public final int addAndGet(int delta) {
    int current, next;
    do {
        current = get();
        next = current + delta;
    } while (!compareAndSet(current, next));
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`compareAndSet` or just `CAS` relates to nonblocking thread-safe algorithms. The increment operation in case of `addAndGet` is fetching the old value, transform it to the new value and using CAS *tries* to set the new value, if `current` wasn't modified during increment. If `CAS` fails, it would be retried until success. This strategy is efficient in cases when there's no extreme contention.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation here is that you will *eventually* `return next`.
Meaning that the condition :

```
if (compareAndSet(current, next))
```

Will be `true` at some iteration. It isn't known when exactly it will happen, so that is why you need to loop until it does. If you look at the code for [`compareAndSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java#AtomicInteger.compareAndSet%28int%2Cint%29) you will see that it returns `true` when successful, and you can't know that it will be successful on the first try:

> Returns true if successful. False return indicates that the actual value was not equal to the expected value.

Comment: Seems straightforward but it blocks execution until the addAndGet returns. Is there an alternative compareAndSet that block's execution so that no for(;;) would be required?

Comment: @TagirValeev my bad, I will update the explanation now